# Running django on IronPython

Tags: .net, python, django, iis, ironpython

There have been some questions and answers here on stackoverflow, but no one asked if it's a good solution to run django on IIS.
Any experience is welcome, both good and bad.

Comment: Who voted to close this? Why?

Comment: It certainly is possible - http://www.infoq.com/news/2008/03/django-and-ironpython There was a video somewhere on the net of the actual presentation but I can't seem to find it anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing I know is that Django has no official support for IronPython - just CPython and Jython. In addition, PIL - which provides Django's support for image fields - does not natively support IronPython, though the [ironclad](http://code.google.com/p/ironclad/) project could help with that. (Caveat: I have never actually used IronPython, this is just based on research.)

My recommendation would be to use a standard Python interpreter to run Django and use either FastCGI or [isapi_wsgi](http://code.google.com/p/isapi-wsgi/) to connect it to your IIS, as Django has more support for FastCGI and WSGI.